# "the situation" vs. "a situation"

Tags: articles

Consider the following sentences

> "brain drain" refers to **a situation** in which large numbers of educated and skilled people leave their own country to live and work in another one.
>
> "brain drain" refers to **the situation** in which large numbers of educated and skilled people leave their own country to live and work in another one.

In this particular example, which one should I use and why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a matter of using 'a' or 'the'. It doesn't make a big difference here, because the sentence referred to here is a general statement. 'A situation' points to a particular situation, whereas, 'the situation' to a commonly accepted general context.

Comment: I'd use **the** as it is used to point forward to a following qualifying or defining clause or phrase, but if you used **a** few would object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether "a" or "the" is correct, simply depends on whether the subject considered is a general description, or a particular case. In your example, "a" is better. Contrast the following:

"brain drain" refers to a situation in which large numbers of educated and skilled people leave their own country to live and work in another one.

"brain drain" refers to the situation in which large numbers of educated and skilled people are leaving Europe to live and work in America.